# nyoka package install conflict with keras/tensorflow version

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, pmml

I have installed `tensorflow-gpu` and `keras` on my gpu machine for deep learning training. The `tensorflow` version is 1.12. However, nyoka (pmml converter package of python) has conflict because of tensorflow dependencies. I think it uses `tensorflow` 1.2. Can there be any workaround for it?

Answer (score -1):

Which version of Nyoka are you using? The issue was there prior to version 3.0.1. The latest version of nyoka (3.0.6) does not have tensorflow as a dependency. Could you try with the latest version?

Comment: This is not an answer. This should be a comment linked to the question